# section text positioned in the margin

Tags: sectioning, margins

I work on a tufte like template and want to make section text positioned in the margin, like this:

[image]

I fiddled with `\@startsection` like this:

```
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}
{ several values }
{ several values }
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
```

but the section text, even though positioned right or left, is always in the bounds of `textwidth`.

I could use `marginnote` instead of section, but I wonder if this can be solved within the `section` commands. Mind that I want to use a `twoside` format, thus positioning left or right should be odd or even depended.

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I tried this:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[rightmargin]{\bfseries}{\thesection}%
  {0.6em}{}
.. or ..
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]{\bfseries}{\thesection}%
  {0.6em}{}
```

How can I use an `if` statement in order to choose rightmargin or leftmargin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution with `titlesec`, `ifoddpage` and `marginnote`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=2.5cm, outer=0.33\paperwidth, inner=2.5cm, bottom=3.5cm, marginparwidth =0.28\paperwidth, marginparsep=10pt}
\usepackage{lipsum, marginnote,ifoddpage}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\bfseries\color{Tomato4! 80! }}{}{0pt}%
{\checkoddpage\marginnote{\thesection. #1}[-\baselineskip]}[\leavevmode\hspace*{-\marginparsep}]

\begin{document}

\section{First section, long title}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{A second section with a longer title}

\lipsum[3-7]

\section{A third section, with a really much longer title. An incredibly longer title}

\lipsum[8-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. Yet, using `\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}` in order to eliminate the horizontal space at the beginning of the paragraphs, works for every paragraph except of the first paragraph of every section.

Comment: @user3060854: I'be modified the code. The indentation at the beginning of the first paragraph was due to `\marginparsep`, because the `runin` shape expects the label and section title to be  in front of the body text.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, but in the second case the opposite happens, thus the first paragraph has a zero indent, and the following paragraphs  have a `\marginparsep` indent. Is possible all paragraphs to have a zero indent?

Comment: You don't bother me. I didn't understand you wanted a zero \parindent. The following paragraphs indeed have  `\parindent`indent, not `\marginparsep`.  It's not enough  to use `\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}`, because it may happen a paragraph ends at the end of a line. The best to do is to  load the `parskip` package, which sets \parindent to `0pt`and `\parskip` to a non-zero value, and takes care of some technical details.